# My Xbox Friend keeps getting kicked out of my PS4 Minecraft world

Tags: minecraft-bedrock-edition, ps4

I don’t know how to fix this problem! Within 5 minutes of loading in he gets kicked out! This doesn’t happen to anyone else on the server. If anyone else is on at the time they get kicked out too. If he’s on with just me he still gets kicked out!!. We’ve tried turning down render distance, turning off unnecessary visual effects like clouds and stuff but it doesn’t help! Please help I just want to play with my friend.

Ps. We are playing together using our Microsoft accounts is that the problem??

Comment: Sorry not server, it’s just a basic Minecraft world

Comment: What error code is he receiving?

Comment: He keeps getting the basic “unable to connect to world” when he can’t join and something along the lines of “you lagged out or got kicked” When he kicked out

Answer (score 1):

There are a few possibilities as to what may be the issue:

1. **You or your friend has bad internet.** If you or your friend have bad internet, in can be almost impossible to connect, due to the high ping. You can try to fix this by shutting off Wifi-intense applications and devices in your houses.
2. **Microsoft is having a temporary issue.** Sometimes Microsoft's servers can go through rough times, where they can stop functioning properly for large amounts of time. Although you can't fix this, you can monitor web issues with [this website](http://downdetector.com).
3. **Your friend is trying to use a hacked client.** This is highly unlikely, but when using a hacked client, the anticheat built into the game can sometimes shut down the entire server and kick everyone from it. I've done this test myself.
4. **You don't have "Allow friends to join" enabled.** You can enable this by going into the main menu and clicking the button to enable it.

Those are the only issues I can think of that would cause him joining to kick everyone else off of the server with him.

Comment: Point 3 about the clients I don't think really applies here since this seems to be about consoles and not PC.

Comment: I do have pretty crappy internet but when other people besides him join it works fine, and he’s says his WiFi is really good and never lags. No.2 is possible, but No.3 isn’t Viable because He plays the game exclusively on survival and hates all cheats. And No.4 is also wrong because he’s joined the world multiple times and Begun to play but he gets kicked out within five minutes of being on. Thanks for the help tho

Comment: @AnAloneGoose If the host has bad wifi, then it will be difficult for anyone, including people with good wifi, to play.

Answer (score -1):

Here are some things you should try:

1. Lower view distance.
   Since your explanation is common to internet issues, try lowering view distance.
2. Contact Minecraft.
   Minecraft itself should be able to sort ANY form of internet issue problems, so they can hopefully find something out. [<sub>Minecraft Feedback</sub>](https://feedback.minecraft.net/hc/en-us)
3. Uninstall Minecraft.
   You might have already done this, but it is good to mention it because it kind of forgets game data.

---

A hard option is that your friend has his role set to `None` on the Game Panel, so you need to stop that, go to the players tab to disable it:

**For the "unable to connect to world" issue:**

> If Minecraft is not allowed in the Firewall, the “Unable to connect to world” issue can happen. You can connect to the internet but can't join each other's world. So check the Firewall settings and ensure the Minecraft executable file “javaw.exe” is allowed in the Firewall.

Comment: [Please don't participate in edit wars.](//meta.arqade.com/q/4992/28182). @Penguin - While editing for clarity is acceptable, always remember to respect the original author. Wabbit - a single downvote is not 'serial downvoting', and we don't 'punish' users for single downvotes. please see [What is serial voting and how does it affect me?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/126829/179041)